# Create a bidirectional infinite ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, infinite-scroll, flutter-listview

I mean in both axis, horizontal and vertical.

I tried nesting two `ListView.builder` but they don't scroll together as I would like.

[image]

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, x) {
                return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, y) {
                      return Container(
                          height: 100, child: Text("${y.toString()}"));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

Possible solutions I have in mind:

- Make the `ListView.builder`s scroll together. But I think that solution may not be efficient performance wise, since flutter still treating each column as an individual scroller
- Create a finite `ListView.builder` and rebuild it as necessary to make the illusion it is infinite. But that may add unnecessary complexity to the project.
- Add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` on vertical axis and perform the scroll with another Widget. I failed attempting that. That method just worked for me if the list is finite.

Is there any widget appropriated to that application that I could be maybe missing?
Is there any other better approach to create something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional scrolling is supported by `DataTable` (try the Flutter Gallery "Data tables" demo) and Table. Maybe try building a schedule widget based on on of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap `DataTable` inside two `SingleChildScrollView` widgets to achieve bidirectional scrolling..

By using something like this

```
               SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: DataTable(
                        dataRowHeight: 50,
                        dividerThickness: 5,
                        horizontalMargin: 15,
                        columnSpacing: 13,
                        showBottomBorder: true,
                        headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                            Colors.blueGrey[100]),
                        columns: [
                          DataColumn(
                            label: Text(
                              "Module Name",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                // fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                            numeric: false,
                          ),
                       
                        ],
                        rows: data
                            .map((details) => DataRow(
                                  cells: [
                                    DataCell(
                                      Text(
                                        details.name,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  //list of cells: remenber the number of DataColumn and DataCell should be same
                                  ],
                                ))
                            .toList()),
                  ),
                );
```

To fetch data from internet you can wrap the first `SingleChildScrollView` with `FutureBuilder`

PS: here `data` is list of modules data fetch from internet,
just for example I have added only one `DataColumn` you can add as needed